# voltage regulator

Tags: esp8266, voltage

This may not be the best pace to ask this but I have to use a 3.3v regulator with this [esp12](https://robu.in/product/esp-12f/)
. For that I have selected this regulator [3,3v regulator](https://robu.in/product/ams1117-3-3v-1a-sot-223-voltage-regulator-ic-pack-of-5-ics/) and in the discribtion it is saying to use two capacitors . so are the capacitors compulsory or not and what will happen if i dont use the capacitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are compulsory. They are to prevent oscillation of the regulator and to provide rapid delivery of current over short periods while the regulator adjusts to changing demands.

Comment: u guys are a company right and the account is not managed by an individual right.

Comment: I am an an individual and a company. What does that matter anyway?

Comment: just asking i checked ur profile and clicked on the links and found that u have a well maintained web site.

Comment: Not as well as it could be. I'm in the process of a complete re-write using Laravel and Vue.JS.

Comment: is the chip kit lenny made by you its a good and powerful board .

Comment: Yes, that's my design. Glad you like it.

Comment: Majenko is one of the top contributors to this message board. He knows of what he speaks. (And yes, a regulator chip is only part of a regulator circuit. You need capacitors to create the finished voltage regulator.)